# How to set a property of scope in the controller when it is available in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a global JS object called instance_

It has a property called current_

Which later gets a property called dataset_

so basicaly `instance_.current_.dataset_`

I use this dataset_ property in a div to show current dataset. But when the controller is initiliased by angular current_ is null. So I cant use dataset_ property of current_ as I cant set `$scope = instance_.current_.dataset_`as`current_`is`null`

How do I solve this?

an alternative attempt at a solution, how can I delay this particular controller's initialization until current_view_ remains null?

Answer (score 0):

This may be one solution.  Add a factory to your app, like this:

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('myGlobalDataSet', function(){
    return instance_.current_.dataset_;
});
```

Then pass the factory's value into your controller:

```
function myController($scope, myGlobalDataSet) {
  $scope.myGlobalDataSet = myGlobalDataSet;
}
```

Then within your views you should be able to access the myGlobalDataSet variable.  If you tie it with an ng-model then it should bind your global value with the details of the view.