# How to share custom datatypes between modules?

Tags: angularjs, model

In my project, I have created a custom type, `MyType`.  I want to use it in multiple angular modules, but I'm not sure of the correct way of doing it.  My initial guess is to create a service that exposes the custom type, but that seems a bit over complicated.  I have my demo code of that method below and a live demo can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/deafcheese/GS4tN/.

Is there a better way?  I want to keep things contained within modules, so I don't want to expose the custom type as a global.

Defines a service with custom type:

```
//this code is in file myproject.js
(function(angular, undefined) {
  //custom type
  function MyType(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  MyType.prototype.toString = function(){
    return '[MyType ' + this.name+ ']';
  };

angular.module('myproject', [])

  .service('myProjectService', function() {
    //hack to expose MyType
    this.MyType = MyType
  });

}(angular));
```

First Controller:

```
//this code is in file modulea.js
(function(angular, undefined) {
angular.module('myproject.modulea', ['myproject'])

  .controller('ControllerA', function($scope,myProjectService) {
    var MyType = myProjectService.MyType,
        myInstance = new MyType('in controller a'); 
    $scope.myInstance = myInstance;
  });

}(angular));
```

Second controller:

```
//this code is in file moduleb.js
(function(angular, undefined) {

angular.module('myproject.moduleb', ['myproject'])

  .controller('ControllerB', function($scope,myProjectService) {
var MyType = myProjectService.MyType,
        myInstance = new MyType('in controller b'); 
    $scope.myInstance = myInstance;
  });

}(angular));
```

UPDATE:
I created http://jsfiddle.net/deafcheese/GS4tN/1/ that uses a constant instead of a service:

```
angular.module('myproject', [])

.constant('myProjectsModel', {MyType:MyType});

}(angular));
```

Does it matter?  Would one be better to the other?  I believe constants are supposed to be loaded before other providers, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently using something similar, but the service *is* the constructor:

```
app.service("MyType", function() {
    function MyType(name) { ... }

    MyType.prototype.toString = function() { ... };
    // etc

    return MyType;
});

app.controller("ControllerA", function($scope, MyType) {
    // use MyType (the service which is actually the constructor) directly
    var x = new MyType(...);
});
```

I don't know if this is *THE* best way, but it works and I have no other objections to it, so it is OK for me.

Comment: An angular `factory` would also be a good possibility here too.  That would pre-instantiate the MyType object and would give you an instance of it, rather than just the class, but I'm not sure which would be preferred in @pgreen2's question.

Comment: In my case I want the class (I am creating many instances of it). If I judge well from this part of the OP's code: `myInstance = new MyType('in controller b');`, pgreen2 is creating many instances too. The factory method would indeed be the way to go if you wanted a singleton.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos, you certainly are confirming my thoughts.  I considered your method, but I chose not to make the service the constructor because I didn't want to create a new service for each custom type.  By making it a property on the service, I could have multiple custom types grouped by a single service.  I should have made that more clear.

Comment: What about using a constant instead of a service?

Comment: @pgreen2 "...new service for each custom type": Yes, that is reasonable. We didn't mind having more services, and in some places we even return other classes as static members of the main class (see public inner classes in the Java world). What I mean is: `function MyType(){...} function MyOtherType(){...} MyType.MyOtherType = MyOtherType; return MyType;`. Using constant instead of service is valid, unless you have dependencies!

Answer (score 0):

To share a type; I have been doing this:

First, create a JavaScript file with the type; MyType.js:

```
MyType = function MyType() {
 someInstanceVariable : "some default value";
 // whatever else you need in here
}
```

The 'import' that file into your HTML:

```
<script src="MyType.js"></script>
```

Then that custom type is available anywhere; whether that is inside AngularJS Controllre or somewhere else, you can do:

```
var myTypeInstance = new MyType();
console.log(myTypeInstance);
```

You can use the console.log to prove you are creating an instance of your type and not just some random object.

I'd say this approach does make the type 'Global' which you said you didn't want.  Why is that undesirable?

If you want to share a single instance of the type; I have been using an Angular factory, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405802/how-to-set-a-property-of-scope-in-the-controller-when-it-is-available-in-angular/19405914#19405914), however I've never tried to share a single instance between multiple modules.

Comment: I'm definitely not a fan of this method.  That leaves your `MyType` class in the global namespace and doesn't allow for any dependency checking or modular testing.  @Nikos's answer is much more "Angular".

Comment: @tennisgent It does leave MyType in the global namespace; but I don't understand your reasons as to why that is a bad thing. Feel free to call me clueless here.  What type of dependency checking are you doing and when?  How does it prevent modular testing?  Isn't it better to make types which are independent of the Angular framework; or am I taking concepts from other languages that shouldn't apply to JavaScript?

Comment: You typically do dependency checking when you do unit tests.  In order to test the `ControllerB` module, you can't easily "mock" the `MyType` class.  By turning it into a service, it allows you to mock this provider in the unit test and then you can focus on testing the `ControllerB` code, 100% independent of any other classes/files being available.  If `MyType` is global, it makes doing mocks much more difficult.